# Using LINQ to SQL to populate image

Tags: linq-to-sql, image

Good afternoon all, a little puzzler for you.

I have a sql table that contains an AccountId and an AccountLogoFilePath (the images are stored in a folder rather than in the table itself).

How would I go about using LINQ to SQL in populating an image using this file path method (in c#)

I've done something similar in SSRS so I am asusming something along those lines is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would, "use LINQ to SQL in populating an image using this file path" that is.

You could retrieve the file path but then you would need to use other classes in the framework to load the image into either a bitmap or memorystream...depends on your desired output.